# How do I produce a final rendered image using Cycles in Blender 2.8 in the Image Editor, as before?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

There doesn't seem to be a button that when pressed would produce a render in the image editor, to the specifications made in the rendering options.

Answer (score 1):

This is still possible. You can configure it in *Render > Display Mode > Image Editor*

[image]